# Convex, non-negative function starting from 0

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $h(x)$ be defined for $x \ge 0$. Suppose that $h(x)$ is non-negative and convex with $h(0) = 0$. I need to show that for $x_2 \ge x_1$ $h(x_2)\ge h(x_1)$.

I need to do this from the definition of convexity: for $\lambda \in[0,1]$, and $x_1,x_2 \in[0, \infty]$ then $h(\lambda x_1 + (1 - \lambda)x_2) \le \lambda h(x_1) + (1 - \lambda)h(x_2)$.

I drew a picture of this, and it seems obvious that the statement holds. My argument is that because $h(0) = 0$, and $h(x)$ is non-negative, then $h'(0) \ge 0$. Since $h(x)$ is convex, $h'(x)$ is increasing, and therefore $h'(x) \ge  0$ for all $x$, which means $h(x)$ is an increasing function.

But, even though the claim is clear, I need to be rigorous about this, and not mention that it is obvious from looking at derivatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: I will prove it using contradiction, i.e. assume that $h(x_2)<h(x_1)$.
We can express $x_1$ as $x_1=\lambda x_2+(1-\lambda)0$, where $0\le\lambda\le1$.
By the definition of convexity, 
$$h(x_1)=h(\lambda x_2+(1-\lambda)0)\le \lambda h(x_2).$$

So, this is a contradiction.

Comment: I tried doing this by contradiction but got nowhere so I tried showing that h(x) wouldn't be convex if the claim didn't hold, any other hints?

Comment: So there exists another point h(x_3) between h(x_2) and h(x_1) and this will somehow violate convexity of h? This seems weird, for one I'm not making any use of h(0) = 0 which is a critical assumption.

Comment: @user7348: HINT: Let you can express $x_1$ as $x_1=\lambda x_2+(1-\lambda)0$, where  $0\le\lambda\le1$

Comment: $0\le x_1\le x_2$...

Comment: I'm not getting anywhere with your hint.

Comment: @user7348: I have edited my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21561/discussion-between-user7348-and-freak-warrior).